# html5 boilerplate conditional css statements - display issue?

Tags: conditional-statements, html5boilerplate

Using Google fonts and the code below on my site.  The top adds an ie8 class so I can remove any references of the fonts in my css.  The bottom adds the fonts css only if ie9 or not ie.

The 'problem' is when I upload this to the server and test it.  Works fine in ff, moz, opera, and ie9.  When I use developer tools in ie9 (f12) to switch browser mode to ie8  or ie7 the page is blank.  The source code can be viewed, but nothing displays.

Now, doing the same thing locally (using xampp) it works as expected.  I don't understand why this does not work when 'live'.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lte IE 8 ]> <html class="ie8" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 8)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test</title>
<meta name="description" content="test">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/base.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" type="text/css">
<!--[if (gt IE 8)|!(IE)]><!-->
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kite+One|Open+Sans:400italic,400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Ugh... comments were being removed when publishing through an optimization setting.  Making sure comments stayed did the trick.